# Drawing 2D array onto a grid

Tags: java, arrays, grid, drawing

I am making a board game called "Go" based of the actual board game. Basically, there are 2 players (White and Black) and they take turns placing white and black stones on the intersections of the board game grid.

So far I have been able to draw the stone, alternate between players and change the value in my 2D array, where 0 = open spot, 1 = white, and 2 = black.

I want to draw the corresponding stone from the 2D array onto my board. I am able to draw the correct stone and make it follow my mouse but once I click on the location I want it to be placed at the location and stay there.

This is what I use to make the stone follow my mouse

```
if (turn == 1) {
    g2d.drawImage(s.getBlackStone(),
                  s.getBlackX() - Frame.frameLocation.x - 15,
                  s.getBlackY() - Frame.frameLocation.y - 35, null);
} else {
    g2d.drawImage(s.getWhiteStone(),
                  s.getWhiteX() - Frame.frameLocation.x - 15,
                  s.getWhiteY() - Frame.frameLocation.y - 35, null);
}
```

What I was thinking is I have a method that is called every time I press my mouse button and the method will get the grid location where my mouse is clicked and whos turn it is and draw the image. What are your guys thoughts on this?

Comment: Is `Frame` a variable or a class? If it's a variable it should be called `frame`. If it's a class then (a) you shouldn't use static variables for location and (b) you shouldn't hide `java.awt.Frame`. Also, graphics contexts draw with respect to the component, not the screen.

Comment: That sounds appropriate. Get the grid location, and place/draw the stone there.  Not sure what else you would really do

Comment: Also please take a look at enums: use `public enum Player { WHITE, BLACK }` in conjunction with `if (turn == Player.WHITE)`.

Answer (score 2):

I normally make a Stone class, which has variables like the status (black, white or empty), the number of liberties, and the location within the array. The 2D array is just an array of instances of the Stone class. If the status variable is not empty, then I paint a black or white stone on the cell corresponding to the location in the array.

If you just use an array containing a number representing a stone, then you will run into problems when you need to deal with captures.

In answer to your question, find the location of their click on the grid, update all of the affected Stones in the array, then repaint the array.